# How to set custom shortcut in vim?

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I want to make use of *Shift+Tab* to left-shift (unindent) a block of text, instead of *Ctrl+d*. How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

The basics of simple mappings are explained in Vim's excellent user manual at [`:help 05.4`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#05.4).

You want some key combination (Shift + Tab) to do what's already provided by Vim's Ctrl + D command, so you *map* `<S-Tab>` (using [`:help key-notation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation) now) to `<C-d>`. As Vim is a *mode-based* editor, you need to consider the mode; [`:help i_CTRL-D`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/IndentCommentPrefix.txt.html#i_CTRL-D) is for *insert mode*.

As your target is a built-in Vim command, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

```
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>
```

To try this out, just execute the above command (entering *command-line mode* via `:`, and concluding with Enter). To make this persist across Vim sessions, put it into your `~/.vimrc` configuration, and restart Vim.

The original `<C-d>` command will still work; you've just created an alias. As you've defined an alternative, you could remap that key now, or (if it bothers you, if you frequently mistakenly trigger it) turn it off by mapping to the special `<Nop>` target:

```
inoremap <C-d> <Nop>
```

Comment: Is shift tab really mappable though? Or is it the same as control I?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: If Shift-Tab is different from Tab (and it is for me, even in the terminal), then it's also different from Ctrl-I.